# Movement packets

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I had an idea of having two synced minecraft instances on one pc(one client is in a multiplayer server and the other one is in a single plyer world on the same seed and the same location). I want to have the player movements of those instances to be in sync (When you move around in the single player world, you also move in the multiplayer world). So someone suggested that I should install a mod that sniffs all the packets sent by the server and the client on the single player instance and store them inside logs.txt. The problem is that I don't know how to take live input from the log file and then use only the movement packets to apply to the other instance that is in the multiplayer world. If anyone has ideas then drop them here.
I have also tried using pynput, pyautogui and threading but it was glitchy and the keyboard and mouse replay was out of sync.

Thanks!

Comment: But what if a player was hit by a zombie on one client and wasn't on other? The knockback from damage would de-sync the position. Should all forces that happen to client A be also applied to client B?

Comment: Well, all the movements don't have to be in sync, you could filter out the knockback packets or detect whether a zombie is hitting you. My main goal is to have just the player movement events be in sync. Got any ideas, drop them below:)

Comment: So you would need to create a mod that captures movement packets and sends them to a different client. You don't need to store them in file.